# How to render mongodb _id in html in ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using ajax function to fetch employees like below lines of code. I am trying to add mongodb _id field in checkbox id attribute. After rendering in browser the output is as

```
               <input id="[object Object]" type="checkbox">

                   $.ajax({
                        url: 'index.php?action=fetchEmployees',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        data: {department: department},
                        success: function (data) {

                            $('.filter-table').css("display","block");
                            $('.dataTables-example tbody').empty();

                            if (data.length) {
                                    var k = 0;
                                    for (var i in data) {
                                        k++;

                                        $("#studentlistmarkscardbody").append('<tr>' +
                                        '<td style="text-align: center;">' + '<div class="checkbox checkbox-success"><input id="'+ data[i]['_id'].valueOf() +
                                        '" type="checkbox"/><label></label></div></td>'
       ...
       ...
       }
     }
   });
```

The json data is as

```
      {
    "_id" : ObjectId("57b328a71999967009987"},
    "Photo" : "",
    "EmployeeNumber" : "4395",
    "JoiningDate" : ISODate("201
    "FullName" : "Julia Ramirez"
    "Email" : "jmorgan2@godaddy.
    "Gender" : "Female",
    "DOB" : ISODate("1986-06-10T
    "BiometricID" : "3",
    "Department" : ObjectId("570
    "Category" : "Rev",
    "Position" : "sociis natoque
    "Grade" : "consequat morbi"
    }
```

I have tried  data[i]['_id'].valueOf() but it is not working...
Please help !!!

Comment: what is the JSON response?

Comment: console.log (data) check the object data, how does the response data object look like?

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
data[i]['_id'].str
```

*Returns the Hexadecimal string value for the new ObjectId.

Comment: now it is rendered as <input id="undefined" type="checkbox"> Please help

Comment: Im your success body. Try native for loop for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { console.log (data [i]['_id'].str); } What is the output?

Comment: In console the output is undefined.

Comment: if i remove str then output is like $id
:
"57b328a711391610180010a5"
__proto__
:
Object{.,,,}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data[i]['_id'].toHexString()
// Convert the new ObjectID back into a hex string using the toHexString function
```

Reference from [mongodb.github.io](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
data[i]['_id']['$id'].toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

data[i]['_id']['$id'].toString   .to string help you convert  mongo id to string

Comment: You posted the same answer twice. Consider editing your other post instead